# Xml serialization Base class attributes

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Im using XmlSerializer class to serialize a Derived class "MyContext" which inherits a base Class "BaseClass". The Base class attributes "attr1", "attr2" are not present in the serialized XML output.I need these attributes in the Context class and the nested class within Context class. Please help whats missing here.

```
namespace MyConsoleApplication
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(MyContextType))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    public partial class BaseType
    {
     private MyEnumType attr1Field;
     private MyEnumType attr2Field;

     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
     public MyEnumType Attr1
        {
            get
            {
                return this.attr1Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.attr1Field= value;
            }
        }

     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]    
     public MyEnumType Attr2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.attr2Field;
            }
            set
            {
                this.attr2Field= value;
            }
        }
    }


     [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
     [System.SerializableAttribute()]
     [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
     [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Context", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
     public partial class MyContextType : BaseType
     {
         private string element1Field;

         private string element2Field;

         [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
         public string Element1
         {
             get
             {
                 return this.element1Field;
             }
             set
             {
                 this.element1Field = value;
             }
         }
         [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
         public string Element2
         {
             get
             {
                 return this.element2Field;
             }
             set
             {
                 this.element2Field = value;
             }
         }
     }

     public enum MyEnumType
     {

         /// <remarks/>
         False,

         /// <remarks/>
         True,
     }
}
```

My serializer code:

```
var mydoc = new XmlDocument();
var context = new MyContextType() { Element1 = "Car", Element2 = "Bike", Attr1 = "id1", Attr2 = "id2" };  

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyContextType));
        s.Serialize(XmlWriter.Create(stream), context);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        mydoc.Load(stream);
    }
```

Output Xml:

```
<MyContext>
    <Element1>Happy</Element1>
    <Element2>10</Element2>
</MyContext>
```

But i want the output as

```
<MyContext attr1 = "False" attr2="False">
        <Element1>Happy</Element1>
        <Element2>10</Element2>
</MyContext>
```

Comment: `XmlSerializer` will only serialize public classes and members.  As it is your `MyContext` class can't be serialized at all.  Can you provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem please?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and your classes and properties are not public.  Once I make plausible fixes to these problems, I cannot reproduce your issue.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ueui7z

Comment: dbc: Updated the code sample as requested. please check and let me know

Comment: `XmlAttributeAttribute` doesn't have an `Order` property so the code doesn't compile.  If I fix that, I still can't reproduce the problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/CWQZ1Y.  Note that you marked `Attr1` with `[XmlElementAttribute]` not `[XmlAttributeAttribute]` so `Attr1` shows up as an element not an attribute.  `Attr2` shows up as an attribute though.

Comment: I have fixed the compiler errors and updated my post. Actually i got the attributes populated by specifiying the "Attr1Specified" value in the MyContext object as shown below.  var context = new MyContextType() { Element1 = "Car", Element2 = "Bike", Attr1 = "id1", Attr1Specified = true, Attr2 = "id2", Attr2Specified = true };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify the "Attr1Specified" value to true. Here is the answer.

```
 var context = new MyContextType() { Element1 = "Car", Element2 = "Bike", Attr1 = MyEnumType.False, Attr1Specified = true, Attr2 = MyEnumType.False, Attr2Specified = true };
```